# SignalR OnConnected Not Hitting But Still Able to Invoke Client Side Functions From Server

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have the following `TestHub` that does nothing but invoke a client side `sayHello()` function.

```
public class TestHub:Hub
{
    public void SayHello()
    {
      Context.Clients.All.sayHello();
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        //do some custom stuff 
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
}
```

On the client, I have the following:

```
var connection = $.hubConnection('http://localhost:12345/signalr');

var proxy = connection.createHubProxy('TestHub');

proxy.on('sayHello',function(){
     console.log('sayHello fired');
})

connection.start().done(function(){
       console.debug('Connected');
})
```

When I call `SayHello()` on my `TestHub` the client prints out the following perfectly fine

```
sayHelloFired
```

and when the proxy first loads, it prints the following to the console perfectly fine.

```
Connected
```

However, if I throw a breakpoint in the `OnConnected()` method on `TestHub`, then it does not hit.

All the posts discussing similar problems suggest that their is no handlers being subscribed on the client side, but that is not the case here. How could this be working and `OnConnected()` is never fired?

Answer (score 0):

Your code didn't compile for me because of the

```
Context.Clients.All.sayHello();
```

Line. Context here tries to refer to [`Hub.Context`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.hub.context(v=vs.118).aspx) which is an `HubCallerContext` class. I think you want to refer to [`Hub.Clients`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hub.Clients);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) which is an `IHubCallerConnectionContext`.

I replaced that line to

```
Clients.All.sayHello();
```

And my breakpoint got invoked.
However I am surprised you made it run and got messages on console.

BTW You are right about that, when using javascript clients, if there is no subscription to any event in the hub, the OnConnected methond won't be invoked.
But that is not the case here.